# php generate image curly arrow

Tags: php, image, gd

is it possible to create this image in PHP using GD ? i know i need to use GD and imagecreate, imagecolorallocate, imagedestroy etc... but i have no idea how to do the curve

i need to create multiple arrows with these patterns

- different type of arrows
- different inclination of the curve
- different colors
- different length

**edit:** this way i don't have to look on the internet for arrows (based on a user/client specs). and then later i will add text to the image (for example: click next or follow the arrow). since im not a graphic designer, creating these iamges using gd will be easier for me.

**eg:**

```
http://kennebecvalleycoaching.com/red_arrow_curve.JPG
http://s3.amazonaws.com/satisfaction-production/s3_images/13664/curved_inline.png
```

thanks

Comment: GD is for SIMPLE graphical operations. What you want is relatively complex, and not what GD is intended for.

Comment: Why do you want to create them with GD in the first place? Yes, it is possible to do it but is it necessary? Describe what you want to do with more details.

Comment: @MarcB is there another library i can use in order to create these images?

Comment: @joel, you can do almost anything with GD. For the curving you'll need to use trigonometric functions. Check out this for example: http://bg2.php.net/sin

Comment: oh i see and then print a dot for every coordinate?

Comment: @joel well yes, but you'll probably would like to check at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilledarc.php too

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of doing it server side, you could investigate things like canvas, or [raphael](http://raphaeljs.com), and create the graphical elements clientside. It will be much more flexible, and less hassle.